# math php from javascript calculation

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, math, echo

Hello I would like to send an email with php code. 
I have the following script calculation that works:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onload = function () {
    var total_of_order= <?php echo $order_total ?>;
    var extra_costs= 38;
    var total = Math.ceil(parseInt(total_of_order) - extra_costs);
    $('calculateTotal').innerHTML = total;
    } 
 </script>

<div id="calculateTotal"></div>
```

How can I code this to pure php?
Like?

```
<?php echo $extra_costs; $extra_costs= "38";?>
<?php echo $order_total ?>
<?php echo $total = Math.ceil(parseInt(order_total) - extra_costs);?>
```

As you can see I''m the worst coder, could someone help me?

dfasf

Comment: <?php

$order_total = 1111;
$extra_costs = 38;

$total = ceil($order_total) - $extra_costs;

mail('customer@domain.com', 'blah', 'your total is '.$total);
?>

just a starting point to send emails...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`ceil`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) function, without `Math.` prefix. Also, since you're doing your calculations in PHP, you can directly output the result in the `<div>`, without any JavaScript.

```
<div id="calculateTotal">
<?php
    $order_total = ...; //Defined previously, not included in your question
    $extra_costs = 38;
    echo ceil($order_total -  $extra_costs);
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. But accually it now shows -38...
Als if I put a number instead of $order_total it works. But that another problem ;)  thanx again everybody

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `Math.`

```
<?php echo $extra_costs; $extra_costs= "38";?>
<?php echo $order_total ?>
<?php echo ceil(order_total - extra_costs);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  

$extra_costs= 38;

$total = ceil($order_total) - $extra_costs;

?>

<div id="calculateTotal"><?php echo $total ?></div>
```

Comment: Why are you assigning a string to `$extra_costs` when it is an integer?

Comment: @scartag You also have too much parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$extra_costs = 38;
$total = ceil($order_total - $extra_costs);

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('calculateTotal').innerHTML = '<?php=$total?>';
</script>
```